# How to hide/skip/prevent instantiation contexts in compiler output when static_assert fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, static-assert

When a `static_assert` fires, the compiler tries to be helpful, the error message usually looks like this:

```
examples/foo.hh: In instantiation of ‘const char* examples::fail() [with T = dummy_t]’:
examples/foo.hh:35:77:   required from ‘...’
examples/foo.hh:27:54:   required from ‘...’
examples/foo.hh:42:25:   required from ‘...’
examples/foo.hh:84:94:   required from ‘...’
...
examples/foo.hh:27:54:   required from ‘...’
examples/foo.hh:92:14:   required from here
examples/foo.hh:12:36: error: static assertion failed: my error message
```

The problem is that in my case, everything except the first and the last message is superfluous and prevents the error message from being really helpful. In practice, the instantiation context information can be very long (both the number of contexts and the context itself).

Is there any way (trick, even hack) to prevent the compiler from emitting all the instantiation contexts for a specific `static_assert`? I'm mostly interested in GCC and Clang output.

Comment: Would it be enough for you to pipe compiler's stderr through `sed "/:   required from /d"` (delete matching lines)? With bash, you could easily write shell script that filters output. `$@ 2> >(sed "/:   required from /d" 1>&2)`. Run as `bash filter.sh g++ flags... files...`.

Comment: @zch: That would not just remove those lines from *some* `static_assert`s, but from all error messages - which is not what I need. A more complicated script might be able to do this, but even then, it's not a solution as I'm writing a library and I don't want to force the users to use such a script.

Comment: You can move `static_assert(is_good_parameter(x), "should be ok");` to interface functions and remove `static_assert`s from implementations. Downside is that it might cause some duplication. I don't think there is much more to do at c++ level.

Comment: Actually, I find those additional lines to be *very* helpful if you're looking at it wondering, "`examples::fail()`? Never heard of it. How the heck did I end up instantiating *that*?"

Comment: @DevSolar That's why I'm only asking about "my case" and for "a specific `static_assert`". I fully understand that the instantiation context is helpful in the general case, but sometimes you have an exception to that rule. In my case, it's the [PEGTL](https://github.com/ColinH/PEGTL). The way we (the authors) are using templates leads to some terrible error messages for larger grammars and it would be very helpful for the user to cut away the instantiation contexts, especially when you have a helpful message from `static_assert`.